# @JsonFormat Changes the Timestamp value while Serializing the Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Currently I have a Spring application with some resources that receives different kinds of data. One of the data attributes its a Timestamp and the value is sent in the request. I am using Spring Data Jpa to persist the data in a Postgresql database.

This is how I have my object:

```
    @JsonProperty(value = "control_initial_timestamp")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    @Column(name = "ctrl_init_ts")
    private Date controlInitTimestamp;

    ... Setters and Getters ...
```

My Request looks like this:

```
    "record_insert_timestamp" : "2020-05-18 09:53:24.475"
```

In the database I receive this: 2020-05-18 05:53:24.475000
If you noticed, it changes the time of the whole timestamp.

Also, with Spring Data, all I am doing is *object.save(objectlist);* I am not doing any specially query.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you save this in postgres at your local machine? If not check time at server.

Comment: It happens in both, local and server... but I want to keep the exact same timestamp sent in the request.

Comment: Should you use `control_initial_timestamp` in place of `record_insert_timestamp` ?

Comment: ```record_insert_timestamp``` its just the name of the attribute in my json requets body. It doesn't have to do anything with what is actually happening with the value.

Comment: Before you persist the Timestamp, are you using Jackson or some other json marshaller to handle the POST request with the timestamp? It's possible the timezone is being offset at this point.

Comment: Jackson is the one been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Not what I expected, but actually how it works.

Databases will store Timestamps as per their timezone location of their remote server location and timezone, to maintain a correlation between all timestamps in the DB/tables/views...etc .

When retrieving the timestamp, if you have configure your current location or timezone or remote server timezone, then it will convert to that specific timezone.

There is no direct way to manipulate this, but its actually how it works.

Thanks,

Comment: I also want to mention that to make sure I am comparing Timestamps or ZonedDates correctly, I always bring both days to the same timestamp locally or server side.

Answer (score 1):

Is the timezone different between your app server and database server? You can enforce timezone for date serialization in [JsonFormat by passing timezone](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html#timezone())

Comment: I tried enforcing Timezones using Pheonix timezone or MST and i still get issues... all I want is to store the same date i am receiving from the request, as it is... I don't want to changed or anything.

Answer (score 0):

### Let us know what is the datatype defined in database (timestamptz/timestamp)

### Refer below  link on -- PostgreSQL timestamp

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/

Comment: It is defined as timestamp.